TicketMaster Discovery API returning few/no events when specifying "city" parameter in search
I'm trying to use TicketMaster's "Discovery API" for a hobby-project of mine, to get a list of events in my city.
The strange thing is that I receive very few hits, compared to searching for the same city on TicketMaster's own site.
As an example, here is my request:
https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?size=200&city=Oslo&apikey=XXXXXXXX
As of writing this post, I get 15 results. While doing the search on the website I get over 2000 results.
I tried adding "country=NO" (for Norway), but I get the same 15 item result.
I am using the "Ticketmaster.Discovery" nuget package, however posting the request directly in the browser has the same outcome.

i tried myself and receive 15 results. there is some mention that the International Discovery v2 api is being merged into the Discovery v2 api service. I would guess they are not completely merged on the website and they are enhancing the output with some additional data points, or possibly using the International Discovery Service. check with their support team
